# Checkbox not working on checked to add values

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, innerhtml

I have created calculation system project with javascripts all things are good calculation done perfectly tax include perfectly but tax not included when I click on checkebox, it add when I type something in input field, I want values changes on when I clicked on checkbox and  even when  I type something

**html**

```
<div class="form-group row">
  <div class="col-sm-6">
    <input type="float" class="form-control form-control-user" id="BMS_qty" name="BMS_qty" placeholder="BMS Quantity">
    <input type="float" class="form-control form-control-user" id="BMS_price" name="BMS_price" placeholder="BMS Price">
  </div>
</div>

<div class="col-sm-6 form-check">
  <input type="checkbox" id="tax" name="taxamount" value="0.17">
  <label for="tax">Included Tax</label><br>

  <label for="total_expenses1" style="text-align: right;">Total:- </label>
  <span id="total_expenses1"></span>
</div>
```

**javascript**

```
$('input').keyup(function(){ // run anytime the value changes
  var BMS_qty  = Number($('#BMS_qty').val());
  var BMS_price = Number($('#BMS_price').val());
  if(document.getElementById("tax").checked) {
      var tax = 0.17;
  } else {
    tax = 0;
  }
  var subtotal = BMS_qty * BMS_price;
  var total = tax * subtotal;
  $('#total_expenses1').html(total + subtotal); // add them and output it
   // add them and output it
 });
```

Comment: You aren't doing anything to calculate the value when the checkbox is clicked, what are you expecting it to do?

Comment: I want that to show value on dual function (on checkbox clicked and on typing)    https://jsfiddle.net/ranatalha/pf51ua2e/#

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that the `keyup()` method will only act on an `<input type="checkbox">` when the space key is pressed to activate it.

To avoid this kind of problem I'd suggest switching the code to react to `input` events (which covers any event in which the value/state of an `<input>` is changed).

One approach to solving the problem is below, with explanatory comments included:

```js
// we select all <input> elements regardless of their type attribute,
// and bind the anonymous function of the on() method as the event-handler
// for the 'input' event:
$('input').on('input', function() {

  // switching to the use of const to declare variables that shouldn't
  // change after they've been defined, and we use parseInt() instead
  // of Number() to convert those the entered-values into numbers
  // supplying the radix (base) argument of 10 because we're working
  // with base-10 numbers (this is largely a personal preference, I
  // don't think there's a particular argument for, or against, this
  // change):
  const BMS_qty = parseInt($('#BMS_qty').val(), 10),
    BMS_price = parseFloat($('#BMS_price').val()),
    // here we use a conditional (ternary) operator, in which we
    // assess - using the .is() method - whether the element with
    // the id of "tax" is checked.
    // If it is checked the value of tax is 0.17, if it is not
    // the value is 0:
    tax = $('#tax').is(':checked') ? 0.17 : 0;

  // using let to declare variables that may need to change if
  // the calculations/results need to be modified in production:
  let subtotal = BMS_qty * BMS_price,
    total = tax * subtotal;
  
  // adding the values, andd writing it the element with an
  // id equal to "total_expenses", though I've switched to using
  // the text() method to avoid accidentally trying to insert any
  // HTML elements in the future:
  $('#total_expenses1').text(total + subtotal);
});
```

```html
<div class="form-group row">
  <div class="col-sm-6">
    <input type="float" class="form-control form-control-user" id="BMS_qty" name="BMS_qty" placeholder="BMS Quantity">
    <input type="float" class="form-control form-control-user" id="BMS_price" name="BMS_price" placeholder="BMS Price">
  </div>
</div>

<div class="col-sm-6 form-check">
  <input type="checkbox" id="tax" name="taxamount" value="0.17">
  <label for="tax">Included Tax</label><br>

  <label for="total_expenses1" style="text-align: right;">Total:- </label>
  <span id="total_expenses1"></span>
</div>
```

[JS Fiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/uzLj5n9c/).

References:

JavaScript:

- [Conditional ("ternary") Operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator).
- [`parseFloat()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseFloat).
- [`parseInt()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt).
- jQuery:

  - [`is()`](https://api.jquery.com/is/).
  - [`on()`](https://api.jquery.com/on/).
  - [`text()`](https://api.jquery.com/text/).

Comment: thanks David Thomas, your method worked. Thanks again

Comment: You're very welcome indeed, Rana; I'm glad to have helped.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use [on()](https://api.jquery.com/on/) to get events you need

I think, you also need to change Number() by parseInt()

```js
$(document).on('keyup keypress keydown change', 'input[name="BMS_qty"], input[name="BMS_price"], input[name="taxamount"]', function(){ // or keypress I have the same result
  var BMS_qty  = parseInt($('#BMS_qty').val());
  var BMS_price = parseInt($('#BMS_price').val());
  if(document.getElementById("tax").checked) {
      var tax = 0.17;
  } else {
    tax = 0;
  }
  var subtotal = BMS_qty * BMS_price;
  var total = tax * subtotal;
  $('#total_expenses1').html(total + subtotal); // add them and output it
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="form-group row">
  <div class="col-sm-6">
    <input type="float" class="form-control form-control-user" id="BMS_qty" name="BMS_qty" placeholder="BMS Quantity">
    <input type="float" class="form-control form-control-user" id="BMS_price" name="BMS_price" placeholder="BMS Price">
  </div>
</div>
            
<div class="col-sm-6 form-check">
  <input type="checkbox" id="tax" name="taxamount" value="0.17">
  <label for="tax">Included Tax</label><br>
  
  <label for="total_expenses1" style="text-align: right;">Total:- </label>
  <span id="total_expenses1">0</span>
</div>
```